# Explicit package name and masking earlier declarations in the same statement

Tags: algorithm, perl, global-variables, declaration

I tried to write a perl version of the following algorithm[image]

Here is the code that I have:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use diagnostics;  

    my $s1 = 'GATTACCA'; 
    my $s2 = 'AGTGGGCGGGGAGAGAGAGAGAGG'; 

    my $dist = levdist($s1, $s2); 

    sub levdist 
    { 
        my ( $seq1, $seq2 ) = (@_)[0,1]; 

        my $l1 = length($s1); 
        my $l2 = length($s2); 
        my @s1 = split '', $seq1; 
        my @s2 = split '', $seq2; 

        for (my $i = 0; $i <= $l1; $i++) { 
            my $distances->[$i]->[0] = $i; 
        } 
        for (my $j = 0; $j <= $l2; $j++) { 
            my $distances->[0]->[$j] = $j;
        }
        for (my $i = 1; $i <= $l1; $i++) {
            for (my $j = 1; $j <= $l2; $j++) {
                if ( $s1[$i-1] eq $s2[$j-1] ) {
                    my $cost = 0;
                } else {
                    my $cost = 1;
                }
                my $distances->[$i]->[$j] = minimum($distances->[$i-1]->[$j-1] + my $cost,
                                          $distances->[$i]->[$j-1]+1,
                                          $distances->[$i-1]->[$j]+ 1 )
            }
        }
        my $min_distance = my $distances->[$l1]->[$l2];
        for (my $i = 0; $i <= $l1; $i++) { my $min_distance = minimum($min_distance, my $distances->[$i]->[$l2]);
        }
        for (my $j = 0; $j <= $l2; $j++ ) {
            my $min_distance = minimum($min_distance, my $distances->[$l1]->[$j]);
        }
        return $min_distance;
    }

    sub minimum
    {
        my $min = shift @_;
        foreach ( @_ ) {
            if ( $_ < $min ) {
                $min = $_;
            }
        }
        return $min;
    }
```

This throws the following error:

```
    Global symbol "$distances" requires explicit package name at ./levenshtein.pl line 33.
    Global symbol "$distances" requires explicit package name at ./levenshtein.pl line 34.
    Global symbol "$distances" requires explicit package name at ./levenshtein.pl line 35.
```

When I alter the code to look like:

```
    my $distances->[$i]->[$j] = minimum(my $distances->[$i-1]->[$j-1] + my $cost,
                                          my $distances->[$i]->[$j-1]+1,
                                          my $distances->[$i-1]->[$j]+ 1
```

I get the following set of errors:

```
    "my" variable $distances masks earlier declaration in same statement at
     ./levenshtein.pl line 33 (#1)
     (W misc) A "my", "our" or "state" variable has been redeclared in the
     current scope or statement, effectively eliminating all access to the
     previous instance.  This is almost always a typographical error.  Note
     that the earlier variable will still exist until the end of the scope
     or until all closure references to it are destroyed.

     "my" variable $distances masks earlier declaration in same statement at
./levenshtein.pl line 34 (#1)
     "my" variable $distances masks earlier declaration in same statement at
./levenshtein.pl line 35 (#1)
```

I feel like I am in a catch-22. I get an error if I declare the variable or not. Any insights would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Remove all the extra `my` on lines 33-35.  You only need to use a `my` once to declare a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `my` to declare a variable once, in its proper scope.  It will get cleaned up when it falls out of scope.
2. Use library functions so as not to reinvent the wheel. `List::More`
3. You should also use better variable names. `$i,$l1,$i1`  they are hard to read, but easy to introduce bugs.
4. It would be more perlish use the range operator, so instead of writing

   `for (my $i = 0; $i <= $l1; $i++) {` you could use `for my $i ( 0 .. $l1 ) {`
5. But you probably need `(0 .. $li-1)` instead of `(0 .. $li)` since perl arrays are **0-based** by default, so you may be introducing a bug.
6. I would recommend you write a **test file** to validate the results of your algorithm.

Here is a working (compiling/running, not necessarily *correct*) version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;  
use List::Util qw( min max );

my $s1 = 'GATTACCA'; 
my $s2 = 'AGTGGGCGGGGAGAGAGAGAGAGG'; 

my $dist = levdist($s1, $s2); 
print "Distance between '$s1' and '$s2' is $dist\n";

sub levdist { 
    my ( $seq1, $seq2 ) = (@_); 

    my $l1 = length($s1); 
    my $l2 = length($s2); 
    my @s1 = split '', $seq1; 
    my @s2 = split '', $seq2; 
    my $distances;
    for (my $i = 0; $i <= $l1; $i++) { 
        $distances->[$i]->[0] = $i; 
    } 
    for (my $j = 0; $j <= $l2; $j++) { 
        $distances->[0]->[$j] = $j;
    }
    for (my $i = 1; $i <= $l1; $i++) {
        for (my $j = 1; $j <= $l2; $j++) {
            my $cost;
            if ( $s1[$i-1] eq $s2[$j-1] ) {
                $cost = 0;
            } else {
                $cost = 1;
            }
            $distances->[$i]->[$j] = min($distances->[$i-1]->[$j-1] + $cost,
                                         $distances->[$i]->[$j-1]+1,
                                         $distances->[$i-1]->[$j]+ 1 )
        }
    }

    my $min_distance = $distances->[$l1]->[$l2];
    for (my $i = 0; $i <= $l1; $i++) {
        $min_distance = min($min_distance, $distances->[$i]->[$l2]);
    }
    for (my $j = 0; $j <= $l2; $j++ ) {
        $min_distance = min($min_distance, $distances->[$l1]->[$j]);
    }
    return $min_distance;
}
```

**Output**

```
Distance between 'GATTACCA' and 'AGTGGGCGGGGAGAGAGAGAGAGG' is 6
```

**Have a read:**

[perldoc -f my](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html)

[perldoc List::More](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html)

[perldoc Test::More](http://perldoc.perl.org/Test/More.html)

Comment: Thank you so much xxfelixxx! Great answer.